# Format string: Value 20000 to $20k?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to format values so that a value like 20000 would display as $20k and so on. What would be the C# format?

Comment: How are you going to display 1, 10, 999, 1000, 20100, 1000000? There are plenty of cases that you should specify for the question to be precisely answerable.

Comment: I think you need to give some more details.  How would it display 20001?  What about 500?  Or 2020000?  Are you basically rounding to thousands, millions, billions and displaying the number with a letter after it?

Comment: C# doesn't _have_ formats. I presume you're asking about .NET?

Comment: To keep it simple, numbers above 999 and whole 1000's show that format.

Answer (score 7):

```
double amount = 20000;
string formatted = string.Format("${0:0,.0}K", amount);
```

Comment: String interpolated: `$"${amount:0,.0}K"`

Comment: [Documentation for using `,` like that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings#SpecifierTh)

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to write your own function to divide by 1,000

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
int amount = 20000 / 1000;
var amountString = string.Format(culture, "{0:C}K", amount);
Console.WriteLine(amountString); // $20.00
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do a similar thing, but cannot use the ToString("format") syntax in my case. This might help others though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh

```
double value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,,", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
// Displays 1,235
```

For millions...thousands would be something like...

```
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("#,##0,", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int val = 20000;
            string currency = string.Format("Total: {0}",ToKdisplay (val));
        }

        private static string ToKdisplay(int val)
        {
            string result = "";
            result = val > 1000 ? string.Format("${0}K", val / 1000) : string.Format("${0}", val);
            return result;
        }
```